# How can I tell Helm's `completion-at-point` to ignore certain file endings?

Tags: helm, completion

When I'm using `emacs-shell`, I often try to run files for which a backup (with `~` ending) exists. 

I use Helm, and if I try to auto-complete the name of a file called, say, `seed-rand.rb`, with an existing backup, I get a result like the image below:


[image: annoying-completion-at-point]


`completion-at-point` really isn't helping me here—is there any way of telling it to ignore files ending with `~`? (That's what it does when `helm-mode` is turned off.) 


And if that's not possible, is there any way of just turning this helm feature off without toggling `helm-mode` every time I want to do so?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the behavior you describe above.  I get the same completion options with `helm-mode` disabled.  Also, note that the function used to compute the completion candidates is `tags-completion-at-point-function` in both cases, so we _shouldn't_ expect any difference either.

Comment: A bit confused by this—any suggestions on what to try?

Comment: Also, if I use `C-h c` to ask Emacs which function is running when I hit `<tab>`, it returns `completion-at-point`? Is that the wrong way to figure out the function that runs?

Comment: @abc `helm-mode` should only affect how the completion candidates are displayed --- not what they are.  This is the behavior I observe when trying to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Ok, but is there any way of disabling `helm-mode` in this scenario, or telling emacs to ignore certain completion candidates (though I'm guessing from your comments above that option 2 probably isn't possible)?

Comment: When the global minor mode `helm-mode` is off (it is by default), the behavior of `completion-at-point` will not be changed by helm at all. If you want to turn on `helm-mode` and don't want it to change `completion-at-point`, customize user option `helm-completing-read-handlers-alist`.

Comment: Thanks, I'd tried this before, but I've just changed it using `M-x customize` and it worked this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@xuchunyang solved this (see the comments section):

"When the global minor mode `helm-mode` is off (it is by default), the behavior of `completion-at-point` will not be changed by helm at all. If you want to turn on `helm-mode` and don't want it to change `completion-at-point`, customize user option `helm-completing-read-handlers-alist`."

I had success when performing this solution via `M-x customize`.

Comment: Why the downvote? I only answered myself so that the question registered as answered on the site, and I credited the person that provided the solution. I'm happy for @xuchunyang to answer instead, and if they do I'll accept their answer instead of mine.